# Recursive wildcards in Rake?

Tags: rake

Follow up to [this question about GNU make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make):

I've got a directory, `flac`, containing .FLAC files. I've got a corresponding directory, `mp3` containing MP3 files. If a FLAC file is newer than the corresponding MP3 file (or the corresponding MP3 file doesn't exist), then I want to run a bunch of commands to convert the FLAC file to an MP3 file, and copy the tags across.

The kicker: I need to search the `flac` directory recursively, and create corresponding subdirectories in the `mp3` directory. The directories and files can have spaces in the names, and are named in UTF-8.

It turns out that this won't work in `make`, because of the spaces in the directories and filenames, so I'm wondering how to do it in rake instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I've come up with so far looks like this:

```
FLAC_FILES = FileList['flac/**/*.flac']

FLAC_FILES.each do |flac|
  mp3 = flac.pathmap("%{^flac,mp3}X.mp3")
  file mp3 => flac do
    puts "Converting #{flac} to #{mp3}"
  end
  task :default => mp3
end
```

Critique, anyone?

Comment: Does this mean you have not found a way to do recursive wild cards in regular make? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make