# How to copy a directory in a Makefile?

Tags: directory, makefile, gnu-make

I have a directory `images/` that I want to copy to `build/images/` from within a Makefile. The directory might contain multiple levels of subdirectories. What would be the most elegant way to do that? I want:

- avoid a full directory copy on each `make` run (i.e. no `cp -r`)
- guaranteed consistency (i.e. if a file changed in `images/` it should be automatically updated in `build/images/`)
- avoid to specify a rule for each image and each subdirectory in the Makefile
- solve the issue within `make`, so no `rsync` or `cp -u` if possible

I am using GNU make, so GNU specific stuff is allowed.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make/2483203#2483203 (`cp` instead of `convert`) But I personally think using `rsync` is cleaner and more robust.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, I'd just use `rsync`. Any `make` script you will create with these constraints will just replicate its functionality, and most probably will be slower and may contain bugs. An example rule might look:

```
build/images:
    rsync -rupE images build/

.PHONY: build/images
```

(`.PHONY` to trigger the rule every time).

Maybe symlinks or hardlinks can be used instead?

```
build/images:
    ln -s ../images build/images
```

If you really want to avoid `rsync` and links, this piece re-implements them somehow (not tested, needs `find`, `mkdir`, and plain `cp`):

```
image_files:=$(shell find images -type f)
build/images/%: images/%
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp $< $@

build: $(patsubst %,build/%,$(image_files))
```

Comment: You might want to add a `--delete` to the `rsync` command to remove files when they are delete from the source tree.

Comment: rsync ignores `-E` if `-p`  is used.