# Makefile loop through files in directory

Tags: makefile

I want to loop over a directory and pick all files with a given extension (recusively) and echo the file path. Somehow this is not working but for what I have read till now this should work. If I run it in iTerm it works and I see the files but when I run it with make I just get empty echoed lines. The amount of lines is correct I just see no file path.

OS: macOS 10.14.5
Make: GNU Make 3.81

```
clean:
    for f in log/**/*.log; do \
        echo $f; \
    done
```

Answers I read:

- http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/tls/bash-makefile-bash-for-loop-in-makefile-unexpected-end-of-file
- [How to iterate over files in a directory with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash)
- [Makefile issue: smart way to scan directory tree for .c files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774568/makefile-issue-smart-way-to-scan-directory-tree-for-c-files)
- and some more, but not necessary to point to all

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes.

First, `**` is non-POSIX, but make uses `/bin/sh` by default. So you have to setup another shell in your makefile, for example, `SHELL=/bin/bash`

Next, `echo $f; \` gets expanded by make before feeding it to the shell. So you must escape it with double dollar: `echo $$f; \`