# Sources from subdirectories in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a C++ library built using a Makefile. Until recently, all the sources were in a single directory, and the Makefile did something like this

`SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)`

which worked fine.

Now I've added some sources that are in a subdirectory, say `subdir`. I know I can do this

`SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard subdir/*.cpp)`

but I'm looking for a way to avoid specifying `subdir` manually, that is, make `wildcard` look into subdirectories, or generating a list of subdirectories somehow and expanding it with several `wildcard` functions. At this point, having a non-recursive solution (that is, expanding only the first level) would be fine.

I haven't found anything - my best guess is using `find -type d` to list the subdirectories, but it feels like a hack. Is there any built-in way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive wildcards in GNU make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make)

Comment: @Jeroen should be the other way around as this question has a superior answer (using `**`).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard */*.cpp)
```

If you change you mind and want a recursive solution (i.e. to any depth), it can be done but it involves some of the more powerful Make functions. You know, the ones that allow you to do things you really shouldn't.

**EDIT:**
Jack Kelly points out that `$(wildcard **/*.cpp)` works to any depth, at least on some platforms, using GNUMake 3.81. (How he figured that out, I have no idea.)

Comment: To search at any depth, I think `$(wildcard **/*.cpp)` would work.

Comment: @Jack Kelly: I just tried that and it didn't work (GNU Make 3.81). Does it work with your version?

Comment: Yes. I'm also on GNU Make 3.81, so perhaps it's due to something else (glob?) behaving differently on our platforms? I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 amd64.

Comment: @Beta I need a recursive solution and **/*.cpp does not work in my GNU Make 3.81, what powerful Make functions should I look at?

Comment: `**/*` isn't working for me. OS X 10.8.2, GNU Make 3.81. It's behaving sort of weird actually...

Comment: I hope this is won't be out of topic, but where I can find a full makefile example that compile sources in subfolders as in this answer? thanks

Comment: `SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.cpp")` also works.

Comment: `**/*.cpp` *does* work for me, but it does not include anything in the current directory (i.e. to get behavior similar to `*.cpp */*.cpp */*/*.cpp ...`, you have to do `*.cpp **/*.cpp`), which is rather unfortunate IMO.

Comment: @JackKelly I would imagine `**/*` pattern to work in shells that have bash's `shopt -s globstar` functionality. From bash man; `globstar If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match`

Comment: `$(wildcard **/*.cpp)` doesn't work for me. It only searches 1 level down. If I want 2 levels, I have to do `$(wildcard **/**/*.cpp)`. GNU Make 4.3

Comment: As Yukulélé points out, `**/*` only works one level down as it is equivalent to `*/*`. Is that not what actually happened to the ones who believe they got it working?

Comment: Can confirm that `$(wildcard **/*.cpp)` indeed does *not* work, at least in 2023 it doesn't, using GNU make 4.4.

Answer (score 33):

Recursive wildcards can be done purely in Make, without calling the shell or the find command. Doing the search using only Make means that this solution works on Windows as well, not just *nix.

```
# Make does not offer a recursive wildcard function, so here's one:
rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

# How to recursively find all files with the same name in a given folder
ALL_INDEX_HTMLS := $(call rwildcard,foo/,index.html)

# How to recursively find all files that match a pattern
ALL_HTMLS := $(call rwildcard,foo/,*.html)
```

The trailing slash in the folder name is required. This rwildcard function does not support multiple wildcards the way that Make's built-in wildcard function does, but adding that support would be straightforward with a couple more uses of foreach.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It returns all subdirectories and files regardless of the provided pattern.

Comment: @Antimony:  (In case you did...)  Do not add extra spaces within the recursive $(call ...) around commas separating arguments.  Adding such spaces alters the result.

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want to use recursive makefiles, this might give you some ideas:

```
subdirs := $(wildcard */)
sources := $(wildcard $(addsuffix *.cpp,$(subdirs)))
objects := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(sources))

$(objects) : %.o : %.cpp
```

Comment: That's a useful list of commands. `subdirs := $(wildcard */)` is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 19):

You can use several rules in `wildcard`:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp */*.cpp)
```

if you need more depth:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp */*.cpp */*/*.cpp */*/*/*.cpp)
```

Unfortunately, and unlike what we sometimes read, glob (`**`) is not supported by makefile and will be interpreted as normal wildcard (`*`).

For example `**/*.cpp` match `dir/file.cpp` but neither `file.cpp` nor `dir/sub/file.cpp`.

If you need infinite depth use `shell` and `find`:

```
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.cpp")
```

Answer (score 12):

[Common practice](http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/slides/make/slides/makerecurs.html) is to put a `Makefile` in each subdir with sources, then

```
all: recursive
    $(MAKE) -C componentX
    # stuff for current dir
```

or

```
all: recursive
    cd componentX && $(MAKE)
    # stuff for current dir

recursive: true
```

It may be wise to put settings for each `Makefile` in a `Makefile.inc` in the root source directory. The `recursive` target forces `make` to go into the subdirectories. Make sure that it doesn't recompile anything in a target requiring `recursive`.

Comment: Sure, but I'd still have to write "componentX" by hand, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Please do it this way. Simply compiling and linking every source/object file in every subdir is going to break once you want to build a library, build one file with special compiler settings, write test programs, etc. I always list every single object file in my Makefiles and sometimes every single source file. Listing a few directories to loop over isn't much of a pain.

Comment: Don't call `make -C` directly. You need to call `$(MAKE) -C` instead. The version of `make` being run could be different from the system `make`. In addition, aren't you going to set off an infinite loop by running `$(MAKE) $@`? Lastly, recursive make is considered harmful by some. See http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/

Comment: Note: with recursive makefile approach, it's hard to get your dependencies right. Good read: [Resurvie Make Considered Harmfull](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `find` shell command, you may define a function to use it.

```
recurfind = $(shell find $(1) -name '$(2)')
SRCS := $(call recurfind,subdir1,*.c) $(call recurfind,subdir2,*.cc) $(call recurfind,subdir2,*.cu) \
        ...
```