# Android cmake is compatible with newer NDK versions?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I'm interested in porting a cmake script to Android, so far I have found [this projeect](https://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/) , the problem is that it looks like it's really old, also in the installation files there are [only references to the NDK r5b](http://android-cmake.googlecode.com/hg/docs/INSTALL.html) which is a really really old release.

There are alternative build scripts for Android ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Documentation was not updated from the very beginning but in fact the toolchain file from that project supports all NDK releases from `r5` to `r8b` and works with `r8c` when explicitly pointed to its location.

If you need complete support of NDK `r8c` features including Clang compiler then you can get the latest version of CMake toolchain from my fork on GitHub: https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake