# How to crosscompile all sources from a directory using gcc-linaro (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, gcc, makefile

I'm running into a problem trying to write a Makefile for cross compilation for a Beaglebone. I'm using gcc-linaro 7.5.0 on a Windows 10 machine.

The problem occurs when I try to put all sources from the directory into a variable for later use.

```
SRCDIR = $(CURDIR)\source
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)\*.cpp
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908057/can-i-compile-all-cpp-files-in-src-to-os-in-obj-then-link-to-binary-in) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036191/sources-from-subdirectories-in-makefile) have previously been posted and this solution has been accepted, however, I cannot seem to get it to work. This line `@echo $(SRCS)` gives me `ECHO is off` which makes me assume that I'm doing something wrong because `$(SRCS)` seems to be empty, hence the message(?) (source folder exists and it is not empty)

Then when the linker is called I get a message possibly also indicating that the directory seems to be empty which it is not.

> "D:\UserData\User\DEV\gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf\bin\arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe" -o hellobone  -marm -O0  -g  -I. -ID:\UserData\User\DEV\hellobone\include
>   arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> make: *** [hellobone] Fehler 1

Comment: Try `$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that solved it. Thanks!