# Bitbake autotools cannot find makefile

Tags: linux, yocto, autotools, bitbake

I am attempting to use autotools to build my project. I am using Yocto and bitbake to make a Linux image.

I have read a few automake tutorials and followed a basic guide I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/DynamicDevices/bbexample). This does not work so well with my current project.

My project structure is as follows:

```
michael@michael-VirtualBox:~/Documents/MAIN_custom/MAIN_layers/meta-MAINapplication/recipes-core/MAIN_Application$ tree
.
├── files
│   ├── MAIN_Application
│   │   ├── autogen.sh
│   │   ├── configure.ac
│   │   ├── Makefile.am
│   │   ├── project.yml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── include
│   │   │   │   ├── main.h
│   │   │   │   ├── scheduler.h
│   │   │   │   └── utilities
│   │   │   │       └── time_conversions.h
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   │       ├── main.c
│   │   │       ├── scheduler.c
│   │   │       └── utilities
│   │   │           └── time_conversions.c
│   │   └── test
│   │       ├── test_scheduler.c
│   │       └── test_time_conversions.c
│   └── services
│       └── mainapplication.service
└── mainapplication_0.0.bb
```

autogen.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Generating configure files... may take a while."

autoreconf --install --force && \
  echo "Preparing was successful if there was no error messages above." && \
  echo "Now type:" && \
  echo "  ./configure && make"  && \
  echo "Run './configure --help' for more information"
```

Makefile.am

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -O2
include_HEADERS = main.h

bin_PROGRAMS = EVCC_Application
EVCC_Application_SOURCES = main.c
```

configure.ac

```
#                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
AC_PREREQ(2.60)
AC_INIT([EVCC_Application],[0.0.1],[michaelminer@smartrendmfg.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.9 foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_INSTALL
AC_PROG_MAKE_SET
AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])

AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

My bb file is also very simple:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files/MAIN_Application:"
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files/MAIN_Application/src:"
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files/services:"

SRC_URI = "\
    file://mainapplication.service \
    file://src/utilities/time_conversions.c \
    file://src/main.c \ 
    file://src/scheduler.c \    
    file://include/main.h \ 
    file://include/scheduler.h \        
    file://include/utilities/time_conversions.h \   
    file://Makefile \   
    "

inherit systemd autotools

S = "${WORKDIR}"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "mainapplication.service"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/mainapplication.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    sed -i -e 's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/mainapplication.service
}
```

When I run autogen.sh in my terminal I get the following output:

```
configure.ac:4: installing './compile'
configure.ac:2: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:2: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Can anyone explain why my bitbake build reports that it cannot find the Makefile.

Edit: Bitbake cannot find my Makefile because it does not exist. I have a Makefile.am. When I rename this to Makefile I get an oe_runmake error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my comments:

I recommend specifying the full project folder whithout specifying `FILESEXTRAPATHS`

```
SRC_URI = "file://MAIN_Application"
SRC_URI += "file://services/"
```

Then you need to specify the `S` variable to the source files folder:

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/MAIN_Application"
```

Also, be aware that `autotools` class will try to look for one of the following files in `${S}`:

- Makefile
- makefile
- GNUmakefile

If one exists it will run `oe_runmake clean`.

So, make sure you name the Makefile correctly and add `clean` target to it.

Fore more detailed info about how `autotools` work check the class in this [link](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes/autotools.bbclass?h=dunfell)

**EDIT**

In order to make sure that everything will go well, run the tasks manually:

- Check the `S` variable value:

```
bitbake -e mainapplication | grep ^S=
```

- Unpack and check files under `S`:

```
bitbake mainapplication -c unpack
```

You need to see the folder `MAIN_Application` with its content there.

- Try to inherit `autotools` before `systemd`.

**EDIT2**

I tried to create a recipe for your Github example link, and here is the final recipe:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=96af5705d6f64a88e035781ef00e98a8"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/DynamicDevices/bbexample;protocol=https"
PV = "0.1+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "b9fb7785e9e1f357f29bef63dce8f1d91adb6170"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
inherit autotools
EXTRA_OECONF = ""
```

it compiles correctly, so, for your case just set:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "\
    file://MAIN_Application \
    file://services \ 
    "

inherit autotools systemd

S = "${WORKDIR}/MAIN_Application"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "mainapplication.service"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/services/mainapplication.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    sed -i -e 's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/mainapplication.service
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add more to my Makefile.am? I do not have a file named makefile without an extension.

Comment: Rename `Makefile.am` to `Makefile` and add `clean` target in it.

Comment: Same issues. During do_configure. I am told that oe_runmake has failed. make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Check my **EDIT** , can you provide me the source code and I will try to create and validate the recipe for you ?

Comment: S points to my directory as expected. The unpack made no changes. I am trying to use autotools. Do I need a makefile?

Comment: Check my **EDIT2**

Comment: That does get me a step further. I have not updated my configure.ac, makefile.am or autogen.sh. oe_runmake is now complaining that it can not find main.c. I believe this is an error with makefile.am

Comment: Yes, so your posted problem is fixed, you are facing another problem now, check this [link](https://yuukidach.github.io/p/makefile-for-projects-with-subdirectories/) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036191/sources-from-subdirectories-in-makefile)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a huge leap forward!