# g++ isn't compiling all of the files in my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, g++, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a c++ project in VS Code but when i try to build it g++ throws an error saying:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -ggdb -Iinclude src/main.cpp -o bin/main 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MessageBus::MessageBus()", referenced from:
      _main in main-244f95.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [bin/main] Error 1
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'make'" terminated with exit code: 2.
```

Here are the files that i think are causing the problem:

**MessageBus.h**

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "../Utils/Queue.h"
#include "../Utils/SimpleList.h"
#include "Messages/Message.h"

class System;

class MessageBus
{
public:
    MessageBus();
    ~MessageBus();

    void addReciever(System* system);
    void postMessage(Message* msg);
    void notify();

private:
    Queue<Message> msgQueue;
    SimpleList<System*> systems;
};
```

**MessageBus.cpp**

```cpp
#include "MessageBus.h"
#include "System.h"

MessageBus::MessageBus() {}
MessageBus::~MessageBus() {}

void MessageBus::postMessage(Message* msg) {
    msgQueue.add(msg);
}

void MessageBus::addReciever(System* system) {
    systems.add(system);
}

void MessageBus::notify() {
    int queueLength = msgQueue.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < queueLength; i++) {
        Message msg = msgQueue.pop();
        for (int j = 0; j < systems.getLength(); j++) {
            System* system = systems.get(j);
            system->handleMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "EventSystem/MessageBus.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   MessageBus* msgBus = new MessageBus();
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CXX       := g++
CXX_FLAGS := -std=c++17 -ggdb

BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE := include

LIBRARIES   :=
EXECUTABLE  := main


all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

run: clean all
    clear
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LIBRARIES)

clean:
    -rm $(BIN)/*
```

But when i try to compile these files together using the terminal:

```
g++ main.cpp EventSystem/MessageBus.cpp -o maintest
```

it works just fine, so i think the problem is that my files aren't compiled together. I think this might have something to do with the linker being unable to find the correct files and it might have something to do with my project structure?
[This is my current structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9yFd.png)

As you can see the header files are located together with the source code. Should i separate the header files from the cpp files or is it that i have put them in subdirectories? Or is it something else entirely? I'm somewhat new to c++ and Makefiles and i can't seem to understand what is causing the problem.

Edit:

**Solution:**

As @MadScientist suggested i replaced `$(SRC)/*.cpp` in my Makefile with `$(shell find $(SRC) -name \*.cpp -print)` which solved the problem. But as @WhozCraig mentioned i should probably switch to cmake to avoid Makefiles in the future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make for compiling — all \*.c files in folders & subfolders in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539422/make-for-compiling-all-c-files-in-folders-subfolders-in-project)

Comment: Please show the link command that make invoked, in your question.  That's the most critical thing we need to see and you didn't show it.

Comment: Or use cmake and stop killing yourself with makefiles. Don't get me wrong; learning makefiles is a great asset; it's just also one that is less and less utilized with the advent of more modern project management tools.

Comment: stop using Makefiles? What is the result of CMake? Makefiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You list the "working" command as:

```
g++ main.cpp EventSystem/MessageBus.cpp -o maintest
```

but your recipe is:

```
$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp
```

The glob expression `$(SRC)/*.cpp` won't match the file `main.cpp`.

If we could see your link line, we'd probably be able to see that `main.cpp` is missing.

Comment: So should i change the glob expression then? I though $(SRC)/*.cpp would include all source files in the src directory. What should i change it to?

Comment: It will include all the source files in the `src` directory.  But in your example link line, `main.cpp` is _NOT_ in the `src` directory.  If that's really true, then that's your problem.  If it's just a typo in your example, then please be careful with examples and use _cut and paste_ of all command lines, errors, etc. rather than retyping by hand.

Comment: Also, you have your other file in the directory `EventSystem`, not in the directory `src`.  So that won't match either.

Comment: Oh, I think I see.  Your directory structure is `src/EventSystem` and you have files `src/main.cpp` and `src/EventSystem/MessageBus.cpp`, and your example link line was invoked from within the `src` directory.  So, it's really totally different.

Comment: The glob line `src/*.cpp` will match all `.cpp` files _in the src directory_.  It's exactly identical to the files that are printed if you run `ls src/*.cpp` from your shell prompt. 
 It won't match all source files in all subdirectories of the `src` directory.  For that, you need to use either `$(SRC)/*/*.cpp` or you need to use something like `$(shell find $(SRC) -name \*.cpp -print)`

Comment: I opened the terminal and located to the src folder and invoked `g++ main.cpp EventSystem/MessageBus.cpp -o maintest` (this time i copy and pasted it). Are you saying the problem lies in the fact that the other source files are in subdirectories?

Comment: oh i see! I will try that

Comment: Just to note, you are not running make from inside the `src` directory.  So showing us how a command would look from inside the `src` directory (without making clear that's what you did) as an example for how make should work, is certainly confusing.