# What's the difference between * and % in make?

Tags: makefile, gnu

Based on the docs, I can't tell the difference between the two. It seems that either of them can be used in prerequisites, targets, and variables to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables):

`$%` is

> The target member name, when the target is an archive member. See
>   Archives. For example, if the target is foo.a(bar.o) then ‘$%’ is
>   bar.o and ‘$@’ is foo.a. ‘$%’ is empty when the target is not an
>   archive member.

`$*` is

> The stem with which an implicit rule matches (see [How Patterns Match](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html#Pattern-Match)).
>   If the target is dir/a.foo.b and the target pattern is a.%.b then the
>   stem is dir/foo. The stem is useful for constructing names of related
>   files. In a static pattern rule, the stem is part of the file name
>   that matched the ‘%’ in the target pattern. (There's more detail in the manual.)

<kbd>*</kbd> when used in a target or a prerequisite list is a [file glob wildcard](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards).

<kbd>%</kbd> when used in targets and prerequisites is a pattern wildcard in either a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html#Static-Pattern) or a normal [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules).

So the `$*` variable has the same contents as the <kbd>%</kbd> matched in that rule's target and prerequisites.

The `$%` variable is used when dealing with archive targets.

The <kbd>*</kbd> is filename globbing when used in targets and prerequisites.

Comment: So, in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make the % is used in a static pattern rule in order to generate the prerequisite from the target which is invoked by `patsubst` in `$(MP3_FILES)` which can be called by `make all`, correct?

Comment: The patsubst transforms the flac filenames into mp3 file names. The `mp3/%.mp3: flac/%.flac` bit is a normal pattern rule (they could have used a static pattern rule if they'd wanted to) which says for any file you are asked to build which matches the `mp3/%.mp3` pattern which has a prerequisite file of `flac/%.flac` run the following rule. The inclusion of `$(MP3_FILES)` in the `all` target's prerequisite list means that `make all` will try to build all those mp3 files.

Comment: So if it was written as a static pattern rule then could the same thing be accomplished in less code? Also, how would it be written using a static pattern rule?

Comment: Wouldn't change much of anything in that specific case that I can tell a static pattern rule mostly just limits the pattern rule application to the listed targets. `$(MP3_FILES): mp3/%.mp3: flac/%.flac`