# To recursively include all files in a folder in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, csh

I am new to makefiles. I want to recursively find all the files in a root_folder and store it to a variable. The code I have written to achieve this in makefile is as below:

```
dirs:=$(root_folder)/*/
SOURCE:=$(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
```

But the .cpp files are not getting included to the SOURCE variable with this implementation.I think my approach is wrong.Any help in this matter will much be appreciated.

Regards,
newbie_in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive wildcards in GNU make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using linux, use find:

```
SOURCE:=$(shell find $(root_folder) -name *.cpp)
```

or

```
SOURCE:=$(shell cd $(root_folder) && find . -name *.cpp)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.But what if the OS is windows with cygwin installation,will it work fine in that environment also?

Comment: `$(shell ...)` runs a command in the shell environment, and cygwin mimics linux, so it should support the find command -- BUT, apparently it's possible for the windows find command to override the cygwin version.   See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/126123/find-command-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-cygwin) for more info.   (I don't have cygwin, so I can't try it).   Good luck.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this through windows command prompt without cygwin?