# In Makefile, how to make wildcard function work for files in all the paths set by VPATH variable

Tags: c, makefile

I have two files as below (from tree command).

```
.
|-- Makefile
|-- dir1
|   `-- file1.c
`-- dir2
    `-- file2.c
```

I wanted to compiles files in dir1 and dir2 directory so I wrote a Makefile as below.

```
VPATH = dir1:dir2
CFILES := ${wildcard *.v}
$(info CFILES = ${CFILES})
```

output :

```
CFILES =
```

So the wildcar function doesn't automatically search paths set by the VPATH variable.
If I specifically write the path in the wildcard function, it works.

```
CFILES := ${wildcard dir1/*.c dir2/*.c}   <== this makes it work
$(info CFILES = ${CFILES})
```

output :

```
CFILES = dir1/file1.c dir2/file2.c
```

I want to add only the existing paths to the Makefile but is there any way that I can use wildcard function for paths set by VPATH? (Suppose I need to remove some files from compile list so I need the files list. Just curious..)

Comment: it looks like you can't.  Details are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make

Answer (score 1):

You can use Make's text transformation functions to turn a list of directories into your desired wildcard command.  Take a look at the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions), they even use extracting the directories of VPATH in their examples.  Consider something like:

```
$(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c,$(subst :, ,$(VPATH))
```

Since you get the full path to the file via wildcard, it seems like using VPATH shouldn't be necessary.  IMHO, VPATH is a bad idea and well designed build system don't use it.

Also consider what you want to happen if files with the same name appear in different directories!