# Makefile Wildcards with different input and output names

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

I have a folder structure in my `src` folder, which I want to preserve in my `obj` folder, where all the `.o` files go. I don not want to use `mkdir`, since many problems arise with cross-platform use. Instead I did

```
$(OBJECTS) := $(patsubst %,obj/%,$(subst /,_,$(SOURCES)))
```

The problem now is, that the input and output file names of the rule that creates those files are different, which means doing

```
$(OBJECTS): obj/%.o: %.cpp
    # whatever compile command
```

no longer works, because for an example output of `obj/Core_Graphics_Window.o` the input is `Core/Graphics/Window.cpp`.

Can this still be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a different name you cannot use implicit rules or static pattern rules.  You must create explicit rules for every target.  To avoid doing this by hand you'll need to do something fancier such as use an eval/call combination:

```
COMPILE.cxx = whatever compile command

define cxx_rule
obj/$(subst /,_,$1).o: $1.cpp
        $$(COMPILE.cxx) -c -o $$@ $$<
endef

$(foreach O,$(OBJECTS),$(eval $(call cxx_rule,$(basename $O))))
```

Note carefully the escaped (doubled) dollar signs.  To understand more about how this works you might read [this set of blog posts](http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read through it when I come back from school

Comment: This looks similar to my idea (construct a list of rules, one for each object), except it's even better because it does it entirely within make.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (because I didn't, so it might not work)

1. Gather the list of all sources with their paths (explicitly, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/2483203/2064196), let's call them SOURCES.
2. Create an explicit list of dependencies: `echo ${SOURCES} | tr ' ' "\n" | perl -nwle '$c = $_; s!/!_!g; print "obj/$_ : $c\n\twhatever compile command"' > rules.mk`
3. Make rules.mk depend on SOURCES: `rules.mk : ${SOURCES}`
4. `include rules.mk`

If you're dumping every object file in the same directory, I'd suggest you forget about the hierarchy in the sources. Then you can write a single

```
obj/%.o : %.cpp
    # whatever compile command
```

and pick up the sources by constructing the appropriate VPATH.

Comment: The thing is, I can't use `obj/%.o : %.cpp`, since the file names are different; the `%` won't be the same

Comment: That works if you give up on renaming the objects, i.e the object file for `Windows.cpp` is `obj/Windows.o`, regardless of where Windows.cpp is located.

Comment: Why does
    ```$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)


        $(CXX) $^ -o $@```

not work? It always chooses the first element of `$(SOURCES)` instead of iterating over the "array" :(

Comment: (There's a new line and indentation before `$(CXX)`)

Answer (score 0):

(This is not another answer, just an explanation to kim366's comment).

> Why does $(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES) not work?

That expands to

```
a.o b.o c.o : a.c b.c c.c
    compiler command
```

This is not a rule that tells make how to create a.o from a.c, b.o from b.c and c.o from c.c

This is in fact three rules; it's equivalent to

```
a.o : a.c b.c c.c
    compiler command
b.o : a.c b.c c.c
    compiler command
c.o : a.c b.c c.c
    compiler command
```

In general, you can have two kinds of rules in (GNU) make: explicit rules (where the list of dependencies is specified by hand) and pattern/suffix rules (where the list of dependencies is deduced). In both cases, the target is a single file. In fact, make has difficulties with commands that produce more than one file (source generators like `lex`, `yacc`, `protobuf`, etc).

For example, you can't tell make that `protoc` creates both a .cc and a .h file:

```
%.pb.cc %.pb.h : %.proto
    protoc .... $<
```

This is two separate rules to make, and I've seen it launch two separate `protoc` processes (with the same command line) when building multiple jobs in parallel.

Comment: Okay, and it is not possible to have differing file names in the `%`?

Comment: No. Whatever the `%` matched on one side, the same thing will be substituted on the other side.

Comment: And there is no possibillity of doing what I want?