# Add functions to be called in Android.mk file

Tags: makefile, android.mk

We can do `call all-subdir-java-files` in a Android.mk file to link all java files recursively. How can we link all c and c++ files using similar way like `call all-subdir-cc-files`? Can I define a function `all-subdir-cc-files` on my own and call it in Android.mk files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add your functions to Android.mk. It's a makefile, nothing more. You should only remember that Android.mk may be included more than once, of you build for different ABIs.

A example of a function that returns a list of files under given directory can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make/18258352#18258352).

As for the `all-subdir-java-files`, note that it belongs to AOSP build engine, not to NDK.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I need to traverse all the sub-directories and get all .c and .cpp files. How can I do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make/18258352#18258352