# add all .cpp files in a directory in make?

Tags: makefile

is there a way to include all .cpp files in make?
I tried this and it does not work

```
# the build command
error_app: error_reporting.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATH)%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $(DEBUG_PATH)$@.exe
```

is manually typing it the only way?

```
# the build command
error_app: error_reporting.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATH)error_checker.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATH)error_report.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $(DEBUG_PATH)$@.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(wildcard $(INCLUDE_PATH)/*.cpp)`.

There's also a recursive alternative to `wildcard` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18258352/2752075) if you want to include subdirectories as well.

Also, don't add `.exe` to output filenames. MinGW will add it automatically, and it's unnecessary on Linux. And don't forget `.PHONY` if your target name doesn't match the filename it generates.