# Collapsing Makefile rules for compilation

Tags: makefile

Lets say I had the following two rules:

```
# C++ source file compilation
$(BIN)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    @$(MKDIR) $(BIN)
    @printf "Compiling ${CYAN}$<${NC}\r\n"
    @$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(INC) -o $@ $<

$(BIN)/%.o: $(SRC)/*/%.cpp
    @$(MKDIR) $(BIN)
    @printf "Compiling ${CYAN}$<${NC}\r\n"
    @$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(INC) -o $@ $<
```

They only vary by the additional directory wildcard in the prerequisites.  How do I collapse them into a single rule that handles the whole directory subtree at $(SRC)/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive wildcards in GNU make?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18258352/2752075)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is use [VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) for this:

```
VPATH = $(SRC) $(wildcard $(SRC)/*/.)

$(BIN)/%.o: %.cpp
        @$(MKDIR) $(BIN)
        @printf "Compiling ${CYAN}$<${NC}\r\n"
        @$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(INC) -o $@ $<
```

I urge you to avoid adding `@` before all your recipe lines; it leads to a real inability to debug issues.