# GNU Make/Makefile: Speedup recursive wildcard on windows

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using this `rwildcard` make function (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18258352)

```make
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    SHELL := cmd
endif

rwildcard=$(foreach d,$(wildcard $(1:=/*)),$(call rwildcard,$d,$2) $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))

INPUT_JavaFileStorageTest-AS = $(call rwildcard,src/java/android-filechooser-AS/app/src,*) $(call rwildcard,src/java/JavaFileStorage/app/src,*) $(call rwildcard,src/java/JavaFileStorageTest-AS/app/src,*.java)
```

However, I noticed that:

- while on linux this is rather fast (cannot perceive the duration)
- **on Windows this is actually very slow**. (10 seconds)
  [SHELL is voluntarily set to `cmd` on windows because the user might not have a POSIX shell in its path].

Any idea why this? **How can I improve this?**

This should work with both GNU make 3.x & 4.x (because on macOS it is version 3.x that is shipped in the devel command line tools, there is no 4.x there)

#### EDIT

After investigation the problem wasn't the recursive wildcard. I could speed up by running `make --no-builtin-rules` or adding `MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules` in the Makefile, or adding `.SUFFIXES:` (with empty value). This removed all the lag observed on Windows.

Comment: The value of `SHELL` is irrelevant here because you don't invoke any shell commands.  You could try replacing this with a call to Windows `find` when on Windows; maybe it has some tricks that make it faster than the brute force method.  But I know of no way to improve the speed.  Windows filesystems are just slow.

Comment: Actually `find` is not a native command on windows. There is `WHERE` but it isn't shipped in windows until Win7 apparently.

Comment: There is a native `find` command in Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find which is what I was thinking of but I forgot it searches for strings in files not filenames.

Comment: You say 'Windows filesystems are just slow'. Well maybe that's the reason because setting `MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules` actually removed all the lag. So the problem was not the recursive wildcard.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `wildcard-rec` function in [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-wildcard-reclist-of-globs) which maybe does what you want. The big upside of it is that it is platform-agnostic.

```
include gmtt.mk

INPUT_JavaFileStorageTest-AS := $(call wildcard-rec,src/java/android-filechooser-AS/app/src/**) \
$(call wildcard-rec,src/java/JavaFileStorage/app/src/**) \
$(call wildcard-rec,src/java/JavaFileStorageTest-AS/app/src/**.java)
```

`**` is the recursive-descent glob code which means that the routine will step down into all subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you. Nice suggestion this set of functions. Unfortunately this didn't speed up the thing in a noticeable manner. After investigation the problem wasn't the recursive wildcard. I could speed up by running `make --no-builtin-rules` or adding `MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules` in the Makefile, or adding `.SUFFIXES:` (with empty value). It remove almost all the lag (~10sec)